# Issue with submitting second step of multi-step form using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a multi-step form using JavaScript, where I need to submit the second step of the form via Ajax. I've created a separate JavaScript file called ajaxRequest.js to handle the Ajax request, which I'm calling from the second step of the form. However, when I submit the form, nothing happens.

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've checked the console for any errors, but I don't see any.
I've made sure that the Ajax request is being sent to the correct URL.
I've tried to debug the ajaxRequest.js file by placing console.log statements, but I still can't figure out what's going wrong.
Here's the code for the relevant parts of my project:

The HTML for the second step of the form is as follows:

```
<section class ="form-section">
<h4>family geographic</h4>
<div class = "familycontainer">
<div id="adultFormcontainer"></div>
<div id="children-form-container"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

I also have a javascript file called increment.js which creates dynamically creates the amount of fields based on what the user needs

here is my increment.js code

```
    function addAdultFields() {
   // Get the number of adults specified in the input element
    var numAdults = document.getElementById("numberofAdults").value;

    // Get the parent element to which we'll add the new form fields
    var parent = document.getElementById("adultFormcontainer");

     // Remove any existing form fields (in case the number of adults was changed)
      while (parent.lastChild) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
      }

     // testing this object will hold the value of the input field
       var adultfirstnameformdata ={};

     // Generate a new set of form fields for each adult
     for (var i = 1; i <= numAdults; i++) {

     // create a fieldset to hold the adult info
       var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");

    //styling the field set 

    //fieldset.style.border = "1px outset gray";

     fieldset.style.display= "flex";
     fieldset.style.flexDirection = "row";

     fieldset.style.marginBottom = '100px'; // add margin to the bottom
      fieldset.style.paddingTop = '5px'; // add padding to the bottom

    /*fieldset.style.backgroundColor ="blue";*/
  
   // we want the adult information to be on the left of the container while the child info is 
     on the right 
    fieldset.classList.add("float-left");

    // a legend should be create for the adult info
    var legend = document.createElement("legend");
   legend.textContent = "Adult" + i;


    // Create a new label element for the adult's name
     var nameLabel = document.createElement("label");
     nameLabel.classList.add("inline-block");
    //nameLabel.setAttribute("for", "adult" + i + "First Name");
      nameLabel.textContent = "First Name" ;  // "Adult " + i + " First Name:"

    // Create a new input element for the adult's name


 var nameInput = document.createElement("input");
    nameInput.setAttribute("type", "type");
    nameInput.setAttribute("id", "adult" + i + "FirstName");
    nameInput.setAttribute("name", "adult" + i + "FirstName");
    nameInput.classList.add("form-control");
    nameInput.classList.add("mb-3");
     fieldset.appendChild(nameLabel); //
     fieldset.appendChild(nameInput);
```

The JavaScript code for calling the Ajax request in increment.js is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('step2-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // collect form data using FormData
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);

  // call the AJAX request function from ajaxRequest.js
  sendFormData(formData);
});
```

The code in ajaxRequest.js is as follows:

```
function sendFormData(formData) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/submitStep2FormData');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

here is the php code

```
    public function postdata(Request $req){ 
     $first_name = $req->input('adult'.$i.'FirstName');
     dd($first_name);
     }
```

the first step does work because the form is not dynamically created and I have a route to handle it.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This bit: `document.getElementById('step2-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {`...have you debugged this? Does the "submit" handler here get triggered when the form submits? It wasn't clear - you said you added some console.log commands, but you didn't show us where you added them, or what output you got from them. If this callback isn't being triggered, possibly it wasn't able to bind the event to the form. That could happen if the `<form` element didn't exist in the page when the `getElementById` command was executed. But that's just a guess on my part. Please clarify things.

Comment: what Im trying to do is to get the name attribute from javascript for a dynamically generated form. here is the code line with the name attribute 

       nameInput.setAttribute("name", "adult" + i + "FirstName");

now I need to get the name attribute in php so I could get the text from the input and submit it to the database. So based on the number of fileds the user creates, it can get the incremented name example adult1FirstName,adult2FirstName and so on. but when trying to access it in php it say the variable $i not found

Comment: Well, you didn't show us any PHP code so we can't help you debug that. Would you like to answer the specific question I asked, as well? Also, Musa's answer below is very relevant and may well be the solution to your issue. Assuming the AJAX actually runs (which would be confirmed if you reply directly to my comment with some evidence), then remove the `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` line and retry it.

Comment: here is the line in the php code that gives the error 
   $first_name = $req->input('adult'.$i.'FirstName');

Comment: after removing the xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  nothing happens

Comment: Nothing at all? Check your browser's network tool and look at the ajax request, and see what it's sending, and what you get back from PHP

Comment: `here is the line in the php code that gives the error`...I can't debug one line in isolation, can I? If you're saying $i is undefined (is that the error? You only gave a vague, paraphrased version...) then you need to look back to where you should have created $i and debug the code to work out why it wasn't created or populated the way you expected. If you want more help with that, [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252423/discussion-between-slim-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object in the request. Therefore you do not set the content type header in the request. It is set correctly and automatically.
If your end point expects data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you can't use form data you can try using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: not sure what to do again

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem
first I  Loop over $_POST array to find all keys starting with "adult"
then extract the adult number from the key
and extract the first name from the value
then add output text to the $output array
pass $output array to dd()

here is the code

```
$output = [];

// Loop over $_POST array to find all keys starting with "adult"
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($key, "adult") === 0) {
    // extract the adult number from the key
    $parts = explode("adult", $key);
    $adult_number = intval($parts[1]);
    
    // extract the first name from the value
    $first_name = $value;
    
    // add output text to the $output array
    $output[] = "Adult " . $adult_number . " first name is " . $first_name;
  }
}

// pass $output array to dd()
dd($output);
```